# why am I getting a Value error: too many values to unpack?

Tags: python

I've started writing a program in Python where the user enters how many spaces they want to move up/down and left/right, and have used the .split() built in function to do so, however when I run the program I get the error 'Value error: too many values to unpack (two expected)' when only two are given. Would greatly appreciate it if someone helped me resolve this problem. I have attached my code below:
/Edit- I have attached all my code below:

```
choice=0
b=0
oldP=0
newP=0
player_location=' X '
x=8
y=0
xi=0
yi=0
up=0
down=0
left=0
right=0
new_board=[xi][yi]
gold_coins=0
bandits=5
treasure_chests=10
a=1
xi2=0
yi2=0

import random
def menu():
    print('If you would like to play the Treasure Hunt , press 1')
    choice=input('If not, press any key to exit')
    if choice=='1':
        print('Great! You have made the right choice :)')
    else:
        print('Goodbye.')
        quit()
menu()
def grid():
    new_board = [ ]

def board():
  new_board = [ ]
  top_row = [' 1 ',' 2 ',' 3 ',' 4 ',' 5 ',' 6 ',' 7 ',' 8 ']

  new_board.append(top_row)

  for x in range(0,8):
    row = [' 0 ']*8
    new_board.append(row)
  return new_board

def print_board(b):
  row_numbers = [' ','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
  i = 0
  for row in b:
    print (row_numbers[i],''.join(row))
    i=i+1
new_board = board()
xi=int(8)
yi=int(0)
new_board[xi][yi] = player_location
while a==1:
    def get_move():
        advice  = 'Please enter your move in two integers, vertical, then horizontal.  Use positive numbers for up and right, negative for down and left.'
        example = 'For example, an input of \'22\' would be 2 moves vertically, and 2 moves horizontally.'
        move = input(advice + example)
        move.split()
        x_move,y_move=move
        x_move = int(move[0])
        y_move = int(move[1])
        return x_move, y_move, move

while True:
    print_board(new_board)
    x_move, y_move = get_move() 
    move(x_move, y_move)  # performs the move; updates the board    grid()
```

Comment: Please show us what input you give to the system.

Comment: traceback or you get inaccurate/guesswork answers (which end up providing the solution, but with greater, unnecessary effort)

Comment: Have just updated my post with the rest of my code! Thanks :)

Comment: the rest of the code was unnecessary. All we needed was the _traceback_ of the exception. Well, it's figured out by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your `get_move()` function returns a tuple with three values, whereas the caller, only wants to fetch two:

```
def get_move():
    advice  = 'Please enter your move in two integers, vertical, then horizontal.  Use positive numbers for up and right, negative for down and left.'
    example = 'For example, an input of \'22\' would be 2 moves vertically, and 2 moves horizontally.'
    move = input(advice + example)
    move.split()
    x_move,y_move=move
    x_move = int(move[0])
    y_move = int(move[1])
    return x_move, y_move, move # three values

    while True:
        print_board(new_board)
        x_move, y_move = get_move() # two values?
        move(x_move, y_move)
```

In case you do not care about these values, you can **throw away the remaining ones**, for instance using `x_move, y_move, *_`:

```
def get_move():
    advice  = 'Please enter your move in two integers, vertical, then horizontal.  Use positive numbers for up and right, negative for down and left.'
    example = 'For example, an input of \'22\' would be 2 moves vertically, and 2 moves horizontally.'
    move = input(advice + example)
    move.split()
    x_move,y_move=move
    x_move = int(move[0])
    y_move = int(move[1])
    return x_move, y_move, move # three values

    while True:
        print_board(new_board)
        x_move, y_move,*_ = get_move()
        move(x_move, y_move)
```

Furthermore mind that `move.split()` **does not work inline**, remember that `str` (strings) are immutable, you need to catch the result, so you should rewrite your `get_move` function to:

```
def get_move():
    advice  = 'Please enter your move in two integers, vertical, then horizontal.  Use positive numbers for up and right, negative for down and left.'
    example = 'For example, an input of \'22\' would be 2 moves vertically, and 2 moves horizontally.'
    move = input(advice + example)
    move = move.split()
    x_move,y_move=move
    x_move = int(x_move)
    y_move = int(y_move)
    return x_move, y_move, move
```

or something equivalent.

Comment: actually, the split thing makes me believe that the unpack error comes from `x_move,y_move=move` first.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: well there seem to be two sequence unpacking commands that are at least error-prone. Furthermore the first (in the method) is a bit dangerous since it is not tested before the assignment is done. :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  ,Willem Van Onsem   Thanks for the feedback! I understand that I should have included a full traceback to begin with, but the reason I returned 'move' was so that the move could be performed later in the code, which is now visible. However, I now understand that I need a different means of going about performing the move :)

Comment: @user5095215 you'll improve over time :)

Answer (score 1):

A full traceback would have been nice, but here the error is obvious: you're returning 3 values `return x_move, y_move, move`

and you assign the return values to 2 values: `x_move, y_move = get_move()`

Remove the 3rd return value, useless since the information is already contained in the first 2 coordinate data

Note that it only fails because python cannot decide how to assign the return values to the provided variables (3 => 2). Assigning to only 1 variable would have worked, and would have stored the 3-sized tuple.

Edit: Willem answer points out another mistake: `move.split()` does nothing, so the unpack error you encouter first is there:

```
x_move,y_move=move
```

(you have to fix both errors for your code to work)